# What’s the difference beetween NSCoder’s encodeObject: and encodeObject:forkey:?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nskeyedarchiver, nscoder

In NSCoder, you can call `encodeObject:` and `encodeObject:forkey:`. And this for many data types. What is the difference beetween those calls? How to use them? Why isn't there a `encodeDataObject:forkey:` or `encodePropertyList:forKey:`?

Comment: just google and you will find hundreds of programs and its uses... :)

Comment: NSCoder operates on objects, scalars, C arrays, structures, and strings, and on pointers to these types. It does not handle types whose implementation varies across platforms, such as union, void *, function pointers, and long chains of pointers. A coder object stores object type information along with the data, so an object decoded from a stream of bytes is normally of the same class as the object that was originally encoded into the stream. An object can change its class when encoded, however; this is described in Archives and Serializations Programming Guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Keyed vs. Unkeyed Accessors

Most of the time you just call the `encodeSomething:forKey:` method and supply a key that you later use to get the value back from a decoder:

```
- (void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder*) coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:someProperty forKey:@"someProperty"];
}

- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder*) decoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setSomeProperty:[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"someProperty"]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The unkeyed version of the call is older, I guess that serialization used to work differently back before 10.2.

### Specialized Object Accessors

There isn’t a separate `encodeDataObject:` call since `NSData` conforms to `NSCoding`, so that you can encode it using regular `encodeObject:`. The same applies to property lists – a property list is just a dictionary, and a dictionary is a regular object that can be encoded using `encodeObject:`.

What maybe got you confused is the number of specialized methods for encoding primitive types like `BOOL` or `NSUInteger`. These have to do with the type system. When encoding and decoding objects, the interface can use the `id` type and it works regardless of the particular object type:

```
// can pass NSObject*, NSData*, any object
- (void) encodeObject: (id) anObject {…}
- (id) decodeObject {…}
```

There is no such general, “wildcard” type for primitive types, therefore the number of specialized getters and setters:

```
- (void) encodeBool: (BOOL) flag {…}
- (BOOL) decodeBool {…}
```

Theoretically you could use `void*` and cast, but that’s clumsy and the encoding interface wouldn’t know the size of the object to encode anyway.

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't understand the reason why the Data and property do not have their mirror method that can be used with a forKey, to retrieve them later... ?

Comment: What kind of object are your data and your property lists?

Comment: Why ? Whatever my data type are, their should be a reason why those methods are built-in like this...

Comment: Well, in Objective-C it’s common to have raw data represented as NSData and property lists as an NSDictionary. And as I already said, both can be encoded and decoded quite conveniently by NSCoder.